# what is wrong with my Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a simple Ajax call to a local json file and my function returns my error condition every time.  I know the issue isn't that it is a file system call, I uploaded it and had the same result.  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="AjaxStyle.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>

<title>
Bryan's AJAX page
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to my AJAX page!</h1>

<div id="menu">
<select id="dropDown">
    <option value="Roberto.json">Roberto</option>
    <option value="Luisa.json">Luisa</option>
    <option value="404_Error.json">404 error</option>
</select><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="Display" value="Display"></input>

<script type="text/Javascript">

$("#Display").click(function () {
    alert("Click handler called");

    $.ajax({
        url: (document.getElementById("dropDown")),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseJSON);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});    

</script>

</div><br>

<div id="other">
<h2>Other page content</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("dropDown")` returns an element, not a URL.

Comment: the problem lies beneath the url, as @meagar mentioned, your current selection returns an object not a url! plus, why use pure javascript while using jQuery?

Comment: if it solves your problem then choose my answer as correct, thanks

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("dropDown").value` or `$(#dropDown).val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check you url data, you are getting id in object format and your are trying to hit id rather than any URL
try this

```
document.getElementById("dropDown").value;
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a knack for missing the simple things :)

Comment: A couple things here.  1) Why use plain JS, when you already have jQuery for this and the rest of the code is using jQuery? 2) `.val` is not a plain JS property.  You either use `.value` in plain JS or `.val()` with jQuery.  In neither do you use `.val`.  So, as written, this answer will not work.

Answer (score 2):

you must use the value of the dropdown.

```
(document.getElementById("dropDown"))
```

this must be

```
$("#dropDown").val()
```

Comment: Also, this `alert(jqXHR.responseJSON);` is not a correct statement since `jqXHR` isn't declared anywhere.  Probably, it should be `alert(result)`.

Comment: the alert will be like this `alert(result);` , the response is in the result variable